# Which preposition is used with "accommodating": to / for /?

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct?

(... The people in the shop, they ...)

- I guess they would be quite accommodating to an American tourist.
- I guess they would be quite accommodating for an American tourist.
- I guess they would be quite accommodating towards an American tourist.
- ... ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to say people will be will to do things

> accommodating to
>   accommodating towards

might be used

> accommodating for

might not have a meaning you are not, except in certain parts of Amsterdam.

Comment: "*willing" ? "are not ___" ?